# View is not updating after scope update

Tags: angularjs

Here is a very simple example of what I am trying to do

```
Athlete.save(athlete,function(result)
{
       $scope.athlete = result.athlete;
});
```

The issue is that the $scope.athlete variable does not update in my view.
In order to get it to update I have to do this

```
Athlete.save(athlete,function(result)
{
       $scope.athlete.fname = result.athlete.fname;
       $scope.athlete.lname= result.athlete.lname;
       $scope.athlete.gender= result.athlete.gender;
       ....
});
```

This gets annoying very quickly.
With the first block of code it's as if angular does not know that my $scope.athlete variable has been updated.
This function is triggered from an ng-click, not some jquery call, I am doing it the angular way as far as I know.

here is a simpler case I made: http://plnkr.co/edit/lMCPbzqDOoa5K4GXGhCp

Comment: what you've shown is fine...create simple demo in plunker or jsfiddle that replicates problem, Try wrapping in `$scope.$apply()`... will throw erorrs if digest already in process but worth a shot

Comment: I made a simpler example which also has the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/lMCPbzqDOoa5K4GXGhCp

Comment: OK...second case works when you change the individual properties...so what is issue now

Comment: `athlete = { fname: 'new fname', lname: 'new lname' };` seems to be creating a new local variable called `athlete`, instead of updating the one you are passing.

Answer (score 1):

`athlete = { fname: 'new fname', lname: 'new lname' };` seems to be creating a new local variable called `athlete`, instead of updating the one you are passing.

A better way to handle this would be to pass the `$index` of the `athlete` to the `updateAthlete()` function and do the following:

```
$scope.updateAthlete = function (index) {
    $scope.athletes[index] = { 
      fname: 'new fname', 
      lname: 'new lname'
    };
};
```

EDIT: see working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/KPu3CSvGIl8l581r9A5o?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/151084

> Primitives are passed by value, Objects are passed by "copy of a
>   reference".
>
> Specifically, when you pass an object (or array) you are (invisibly)
>   passing a reference to that object, and it is possible to modify the
>   contents of that object, but if you attempt to overwrite the reference
>   it will not affect the copy of the reference held by the caller - i.e.
>   the reference itself is passed by value.

This explains why plunker doesn't update.  However, your inline code example (where you use `$scope.athlete = result.athlete`) seems like it should work.  Can you create a sample showing that failing?

Answer (score 0):

I received help from here to solve this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/Ih06VLDH_JU/EtHLrGeMgUEJ

There are two ways, one was already mentioned and what is to use the index to update the original way.

The second way is to use angular.copy(source, destination)